# how to get updated records ids in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am updating multiple rows in laravel .

```
 StoragePeriod::where('customer_id', $invoice->customer_id)->update(['invoice_id' => $invoice->id]);
```

How I can get ids of those updated records?

Comment: the return value of the above statement will contain it, so `$sPModel =  StoragePeriod::where('cust ...`, the pluck the ids from it, using `$sPModel->pluck('id');`

Comment: That is a work around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [tap](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-tap) method.

If you wish to get all the models instead of just the ids you can replace `pluck` with `get`.

```
tap(StoragePeriod::where('customer_id', $invoice->customer_id))
    ->update(['invoice_id' => $invoice->id])
    ->pluck('id');
```

From the documentation:

> If no closure is passed to the tap function, you may call any method
> on the given $value. **The return value of the method you call will
> always be $value, regardless of what the method actually returns in
> its definition.** For example, the Eloquent update method typically
> returns an integer. However, we can force the method to return the
> model itself by chaining the update method call through the tap
> function:
>
> ```
> $user = tap($user)->update([
>     'name' => $name,
>     'email' => $email, 
> ]);
> ```